# aredis.StrictRedis does not work on AWS EC2 but redis.Redis works

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, python-asyncio

I am trying to connect to my Redis server running in a docker that's running on the same EC2, using this code as my whole script is based on async programming on an EC2 instance, but it always ends with

```
Failed to connect to Redis server: ConnectionError()
```

here's the code

```
import asyncio
from aredis import StrictRedis

# Define your Redis server configuration
redisdb_config = {
    'host': 'myhost',
    'port': myport,
    'password': 'mypassword'
}

async def connect_redis(redisdb_config):
    try:
        # Create a StrictRedis instance with the provided config
        redis_conn = StrictRedis(**redisdb_config)

        # Check if the connection was successful
        if await redis_conn.ping():
            print("Successfully connected to Redis server.")
        else:
            print("Ping failed")
            return

        # Perform Redis operations
        await redis_conn.lpush('mylist', 'item1', 'item2', 'item3')  # Left push items to a list
        await redis_conn.rpush('mylist', 'item4', 'item5')  # Right push items to a list
        # Close the Redis connection
        redis_conn.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to connect to Redis server:", repr(e))

# Run the asynchronous function
asyncio.run(connect_redis(redisdb_config))
```

but it works perfectly fine if I replace this line

```
        redis_conn = StrictRedis(**redisdb_config)
```

with

```
    r = redis.Redis(**redisdb_config)
```

can someone please let me know what am I missing?
Thanks